# How read document property inside Firestore Trigger

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send notifications to an Android app's users with firebase cloud messaging. I am using cloud firestore triggers but when trying to access a user node's properties, they are undefined.

Here is my index.js :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('conversations/{conversation}/messages/{message}')
    .onCreate((docSnapshot, context) => {
      const message = docSnapshot.data();
      const recipientId = message['recipientId'];
      const senderName = message['senderName'];

      return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(recipientId).get().then(userDoc => {

        const registrationTokens = userDoc.registrationTokens;
        console.log("registrationTokens  = "+ registrationTokens);

        const notificationBody = message['message'];
        const payload = {
          notification : {
            title : senderName + " sent you a message,",
            body: notificationBody,
            clickAction: "ConversationActivity"
          },
          data : {
            contactName : senderName,
            userId : message['senderId']
          }
        }

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload).then(response => {
          const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens;

          response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            const error = result.error;
            if (error){
              const failedRegistrationToken = stillRegisteredTokens['index'];
              if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token'
                  || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                      const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)
                      if (failedIndex > -1) {
                          stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1);
                      }
                  }
            }
          })
          return admin.firestore().doc("users/" + recipientId).update({
              registrationTokens: stillRegisteredTokens
          })
        })
      })
    })
```

Because of that I get an error "sendDevice() argument must be non-empty array or non null string"

**UPDATE**

registrationTokens were undefined because I called `userDoc` instead of `userDoc.data()`

Now registrationTokens is not null nor empty but I still get the error :

```
Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
```

Comment: You're supposed to access a document's data by calling `.data()` on the `userDoc` in your `Promise.then` code.

Comment: Also take a good lock at what your debug log shows.  I'll guess that `registrationTokens` is not what you expect at all.

Comment: userDoc or userDoc.data() is always undefined according to the logs. This results in registrationTokens to be undefined as well

Comment: After separating userDoc.data() to it's own variable, it seems to be working now. Thanks :)
For some reason userDoc.data().registrationTokens returns undefined.